# Typoscript: Custom HMENU with buttons

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have made a HMENU like this:

```
lib.mainMenu = HMENU

lib.mainMenu {

   entryLevel = 0  

   1 = TMENU

   1 {

      NO.allWrap = <div id="forsideknap">|</div> || <div id="butikker">|</div> || <div id="nyheder">|</div> || <div id="arrangementer">|</div> || <div id="avis">|</div>

   }
}
```

and it is looking like this on my page:
[image]

as you can see the each page name and link is infront of each div. How do i assign each page element to its specific div element ? in other words, i need to get rid of the text infront, so when you click on the div image it has the same functionality as if you clicked on the links which are generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either set `NO.doNotShowLink = 1` to hide the complete A-tag (the DIV-wrap will still be rendered).

Or you can do this via CSS. By setting for example the following properties on the A-tag:

```
a {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 1000px;
}
```

It might also be required to set a `width` for the A-tag, for the `overflow: hidden` to work.